# With which tool I can draw a shapeless and curved logo for website?

Tags: windows, drawing, graphic-design

I want to draw a logo that I designed for one website. This logo is shapeless and curved, like this image that I drew with CS:
[image]

I searched for offline/online tools, but don't find perfect one. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: What OS, what pricing? Do you care about format - do you want Vector or Bitmap? As it is I have at least 5 different programs that can fulfill what you've specified.

Comment: @NickWilde Windows, and I don't care about pricing. Also format is not very important for me, but vector is better. I wait for your suggestion.

Comment: What is "CS"? (Adobe "Creative Suite"??)

Comment: @w3d yes, Adobe Photoshop CS5.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org) and its Path/Node tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>)

It is Free/Open Source and multi-platform.

Here are some tutorials: http://www.inkscape.org/en/learn/tutorials/

Here is how you may begin:

[image]

1. First draw straight lines (1 and 2)
2. Modify them (3 and 4)
3. Right Click a line and choose `Fill and Stroke`. Modify `Stroke` to increase width
4. Save: <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Export bitmap</kbd> will save as PNG, while Inkscape default save format is SVG.

Comment: "Export bitmap" - You may want to keep this as SVG for a logo on a responsive design? All current browsers support SVG, although you might still need a bitmap for legacy support.

Comment: OR: (1) use any program to create "shape"; (2) "open" or "import" PNG (or whatever) into Inkscape; (3) use the `Path > Trace Bitmap...` tool to trace the bitmap; (4) edit the resulting SVG (especially `Path > Simplify` = `CTRL+L`). See [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wUgVy.png) for illustration, using the JPG provided by OP.

Comment: I used Inkscape to design my logo and that's really worked! Cornelius thank you for your perfect help and nice designing. by tools number 1 and 3(in your image) I design what I want.
@Davïd Also your idea is clear and nice. I use `CTRL+L` and that really helped.

Comment: @Cornelius Thank you for your attention my friend... My website still has little more way to become online(when that's become ready to show, I put link here!), but here is the link of my first try of this logo design [logo](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/04/30/logofirst_try.png). I think it's not bad, but it's my pleasure to hear your view about it. feel free to say your view and criticism.

Comment: @pooriahaddad nice design! At lines you may probably use rounded ends.

Comment: @pooriahaddad in Inkscape select a line, then `Shift+Ctrl+F` or right-click - `Fill and Stroke`, select `Stroke style` tab and change `Cap`.

Comment: @Cornelius Thank you again. I do that(for some of lines, not all of them) and thinking [this one](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/04/30/just_for_show.png) is better.